# Displaying Different Server, DB, Table names in Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my C# program I have 3 dropdownlists.

1. In the dropdownlist 1 I have to display all the SQL server names.
2. All database names under that server name should be displayed in the
   dropdownlist 2.
3. In the dropdownlist 3 all table names that comes under that selected
   database should have to display.
   I want to know how to write connection string for this because there may be many servers,DB and Tables.I cannot write connection string for each one of them.**I need to write one connection string that will fetch the data according to the selected dropdownlist value.**

I tried the below code using if else statement and it is working fine.But I dont want to use if else statement.So please help me.

```
string Server1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        string Server2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS1"].ConnectionString;
        string Server3 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS2"].ConnectionString;
        string Server4 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCSLocal1"].ConnectionString;
        private string Server;


protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == @"Anusql\SQLEXPRESS")
            {
                Server = Server1;
            }
            else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == @"CAB3RMIGGA\SQLEXPRESS")
            {
                Server = Server2;

            }
            else
            {
                Server = Server3;
            }

            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(Server);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SYS.databases", sqlconn);
            sqlconn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet sd = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(sd);
            DropDownList3.DataSource = sd;
            DropDownList3.DataTextField = "name";
            DropDownList3.DataValueField = "name";
            DropDownList3.DataBind();
            DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
            sqlconn.Close();


        }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far. Maybe you could use reflection? Maybe something similar to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159881/sqlserver-database-reflection-and-autogenerating-nlog-xml

Answer (score 0):

What is your idea about solving this? You haven't said a word about what you tried/thought so far? Here's my suggestion about implementing (& you will see the problem because we dont know what all stuff you know and are allowed to use).

I would prefer the following class to hold all my configuration

```
internal class ProjectEnvironment
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public List<SQLServer> Servers {get; set;}
}

internal class SQLServer
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string HostName {get; set;}
   public int Port {get; set;}
   public List<Database> Databases {get; set;}
}

internal class Database
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public List<string> Tables {get; set;}
}
```

Assume an XML Serialized version of this class -- Filled up with all possible SQL Server details that you company/project has. That serialized version will be stored and used as my config. On program start I will locate the config.xml file serialize it into the aforementioned class structure and then bind the controls to the relevant properties.